# Where is alias this defined

Tags: standards, multiple-inheritance, d

When programming a C++ application I needed a class that supported interfaces.  After implmenting it with MI is had a big ugh moment when I realized if I wasn't careful I would introduce diamond inheritance and that I should probably virtually inherit my interfaces.  Further, the only elegant way to implement the code required dynamic_cast.

About this point I thought there must be a better way.  When I remember reading about subtypeing/alias this in [TDPL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321635361).  I copied the basic idea into my class.  I think the solution is much more elegant, but not coventional.

To preemptively justify my code, I was hoping that I could link to a page that describes the alias this feature of D.  However I could find one on [the website](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/).

Where is subtypeing / alias this described officially?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/class.html#AliasThis

But I think this might be a little bit out of date. IIRC TDPL describes the possibility of several alias this per class.

Comment: thanks.  Unfortunately TDPL does a much better job explaining how this is used to avoid multiple inheritance.  Oh well, I guess I just point them to the book.

Comment: You are free to fork https://github.com/D-Programming-Language/d-programming-language.org and contribute a better explanation of alias this to the docs :)

Comment: Multiple alias this is on the agenda but currently not implemented.